# Pattern match a NULL character or white space

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, null, pattern-matching

How to pattern match a NULL character or whitespace in Perl?
For Example,

I want to remove a null character or whitespace.

`@x` is having some elements like 0 to 9, including null characters/whitespace.

If i print the array the output is:

`1      2 34  5       678      90`

How to get the output as:

`1234567890`  where `$x[0]=1`,`$x[1]=2` and so on.

Note: Here, between the elements they are null characters/ whitespace

This issue i am facing while concatinating the elements of two arrays as below
@x will have data as"0           1 2                   3"
@y will have data as"4 5                                               6 7"
When i am concatinating the output is as
"0          _ 4 1_ 5                                               2                  _ 6 3_ 7"

But i need output as @z="0_4,1_5,2_6,3_7" where $z[0]=0_4 and so on.

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: @x =0xxxxxxxxxxx1x2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx3                                       @y=4x5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx6x7                                                            @z=$x."_".$y;    The output of $z is                                                                          "0xxxxxxxxxx_x4x1_x5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_x6x3_x7". Here, "x" is NULL CHARACTER . i want to remove those null characters @Casimir

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `\0` escape sequence for a null character and use it in a substitution regex. To run the regex on all elements of an array, you can use `map`:

```
@x = map { $_ =~ s/\0//g; } @x;
```

Comment: Sorry Dondi, it's not working

Comment: @Sam333 Be more specific.

Comment: @Sam333: are you sure that what you have to remove is the character NULL (first character of the ascii table)?